# Search for duplicate prefix of file names

Tags: command-line

I have a folder contains files name as: `xxx.get.txt` and `xxx.resp.txt`

```
   xxx.get.txt, xxx.resp.txt
   yyy.get.txt, yyy.resp.txt
   zzz.get.txt, zzz.resp.txt, etc
```

each prefix `xxx` should have two corresponding files, `.get.txt` and `.resp.txt`

However, now I calculate the number of `.get.txt` and the number of `.resp.txt` files, they are not equal, there're ten more `.get.txt`. I want to find out, which `.get.txt` files do not have ´.resp.txt´ file

Is it possible?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate all the get.txt files and check if the corresponding resp.txt files exist.

```
for file in *.get.txt; do 
    [[ -e ${file%.get.txt}.resp.txt ]] || echo "$file is missing resp"; 
done
```

`${file%.get.txt}` is the same as `$file` except, `.get.txt` is removed from the end (if it has that string at the end).